# How to extract Class from KProperty1 in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, reflection

I have the following code :

```
class User : MyType {
  val address: Address? = null
  val company: Company? = null
  ...
}

class Address : MyType {
  val city: String? = null
}

class Company : MyType {
  val name: String? = null
}

var properties: MutableMap<String, Collection<KProperty1<Any, *>>>? = mutableMapOf()

fun init() {
    fillPropertiesMap(User::class.java)
}

private inline fun <reified T : Any> fillPropertiesMap(clazz: Class<T>) {
    val prop = clazz.kotlin.memberProperties
            .filter { it.visibility == KVisibility.PUBLIC } as Collection<KProperty1<Any, *>>
    fill(clazz as Class<Any>, prop)
}

fun fill(clazz: Class<Any>, props: Collection<KProperty1<Any, *>>) {
    properties[clazz.simpleName] = props
    props.forEach()
    { prop ->
        if (isMyCustomType(prop)) { 
            fillPropertiesMap(prop.????) . // how get class from KProperty1 for Address.class and Company.class
        }
    }
}
```

I want to fill Map with KProperty1 of my class User. The class User has a hierarchical structure, and i need to get all the KProperty1 list of the classes that are in the class User. Question is how get class from KProperty1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
fillPropertiesMap(prop.getter.returnType.javaType as Class<Any>, map)
```

Comment: This is strictly worse than my answer: it requires a cast and that cast will fail if the return type is e.g. `List<Address>`. Of course, it may be that you really want `Type` or `KType` instead of `Class` in your map in the first place.

Comment: Cast exception does not happen because i did a check from above isMyCustomType(prop). I can't to use KType becouse i need map Class to KProperties. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the return type's `Class` (e.g. `Address::class.java` from `User::address`), it would be

```
prop.returnType.jvmErasure.java
```

Docs: [`returnType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/return-type.html); [`erasure`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/jvm-erasure.html); [`java`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html).

Side note: if you have `reified T` in `fillPropertiesMap`, you don't need a `Class<T>` argument because you can get it as `T::class.java`.